# Importing module functions from python packages

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I saw the command listed as below for `sklearn.tree.tree`

```
from ._tree import Criterion, Splitter, Tree
from . import _tree
```

Yet in the same tree folder I cannot find any file or class named `_tree`. Can anyone tell me where exactly I can find this class?

Comment: are you able to find `_tree.pyx`? If not, something may have not worked well at installation. Is the motivation for your question debugging or interest in the code?

Comment: @eickenberg: I don't think the `.pyx` files are installed, since they're not needed at runtime.

Comment: Oh! Very good point, that makes a lot of sense. I just checked a non inplace build of `sklearn` and only the compiled `_tree.so` is present. Same with a packaged version. This may actually be the answer to the question. @user3381299 are you looking to read the code or is there an actual file missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module you are looking for is written in Cython. The corresponding file is called `_tree.pyx`. It can be found in `.../scikit-learn/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx`, if you have the scikit learn sources, e.g. in form of the git repo, on your computer.

Cython is translated to C code, which can be found in `_tree.c`.

The compiled C code is what is imported in the lines you found, and the corresponding file is called `_tree.so`. In a typical scikit-learn installation, this may be the only file you find. It is not human-readable, so if you are interested in the source, check it out [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx)